# Back up MySQL when DELETE query is performed

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

This is quite a stretch, but I am wondering if it is possible to change MySQL's behavior so that when a `DELETE` query is performed, something else happens -- for example, the row to be deleted is added to a backup database.

Basically, I have a WordPress site that I want to be able to recover data from. In WP, you can delete posts and put them in the trash bin first, but users and other data are deleted permanently.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/triggers.html) that fires when a record is deleted from your table:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO backup_table
    (col1, col2, col3)
  VALUES
    (OLD.col1, OLD.col2, OLD.col3)
;
```

Comment: Any way other then triggers? My goal is to clear the DB space. With triggers I will again end up with temp table or csv files on the same server. Thanks